# Real-time Sync between 2 pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, websocket, real-time

I have a project that I am trying to find a solution for.  I am attempting to have an Element (maybe a DIV), between 2 pages, be synchronized in real-time.  After doing some research, it looks like using WebSocket to link them might be the best solution.  I'm not experienced with setting up a scenario like this so have been trying to wrap my head around it.

My ultimate goal is to be able to inject (via JQuery) code into the shared/synced div (iframes with PDFs, URLs, other files) that will show up without refreshing on the 2nd page, real-time, so it works almost like co-browsing, but only a section of the page.

I'm building my app with ASP.NET MVC4/Razor.

Any suggestions or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If you use ASP.NET [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) might be a solution.